# How to print the month days in another div in JavaScript, so that I can relatively position it inside this new div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still working on this calendar project and struggling. Inside the for loops the month days are set and stored in a div called *day_element* and passed through innerHTML to the page. Each day is printed in a new div. But I need to have a body for each day cell, so I can insert later contents for each day cell. Therefore, I'd like to put the days in the top right of each day cell. I don't know how to replicate an outer loop with the one in the for-loop. Can you help with this challenge?

```
  days_element.innerHTML = ''; 

  let selectedDate = '';

  //TODO: the modal does not capiture dates after the current year, a condition for that is needed 

  for (let x = day; x > 0; x--) {
    const day_element = document.createElement('div');

    day_element.classList.add('today');
    day_element.textContent = (prevDate - x + 1);

    day_element.addEventListener('click', function () {               
      selectedDate = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + dt.getMonth() + '-' + (prevDate - x + 1); 

      $('.myForm #date').val(selectedDate); 
      $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal(); 
    });

    days_element.appendChild(day_element);  
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= endDate; i++) { 
    const day_element = document.createElement('div');
    day_element.classList.add('today');

    if (i == today.getDate() && dt.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) {
      day_element.textContent =  i;
      day_element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(214, 215, 194,0.4)';
    } else {
      day_element.textContent = i;
    }

    day_element.addEventListener('click', function () {                 
      selectedDate = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + (dt.getMonth()+1) + '-' + ('0'+i).slice(-2); 

      $('.myForm #date').val(selectedDate); 
      $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal(); 
    });

    days_element.appendChild(day_element);  
  }
```

Comment: Are the above two for loops the two different approaches you tried?

Comment: No, the first loop is to print the last days of previous month in the number of cells remaining before the current month's day 1 cell. The second loop print the days of the current month. In both of them each day is stored in day_element and than passed to HTML through days_element, which is declared at the beginning. What is missing there is link to the HTML class days_element.querySelector('.days'). I's like to create another div inside days dynamically, so it separates each day from the cell it lies in.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look

Comment: Why do all days have the class "today"? So you want to have two divs for each day instead of one? And you would like the day number to be written directly in the cell while the day info can be added dynamically into the cell as a child and written to it?

Comment: Ok, I'll present you a solution, tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank those who looked at the code and attempted to help. I solved the problem and was able to finish the calendar by myself. It looks very different now. I had to restructure the code. But those who might find it useful:

1. I gave a class to day_element:

```
day_element.className = 'className';
```

then I aligned the month days right, using position relative to adjust top.

2. I created another div, such as day_element, likely with a class name and appended it to the querySelector which retrieves the HTML element:

```
const anotherDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
anotherDiv.className = 'otherClass';
anotherDiv.textContent = 'content';

(...)

days_element.appendChild(day_element).appendChild(anotherDiv);
```

The rest I could do with CSS. Due to the complex of the event calendar This solution worked for the structure I recreated, which looks very different from the code I posted. But basically, the approach was that. I fixed the code redundancies as well with helper methods.

Best regards